# Order promises execution in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm working on Angular full-stack with ES6 and babel.

In my controller, I have:

```
$onInit() { 
    this.$http.get('/api/example')
        .then(() => {console.log("task1")})
        .then(() => {console.log("task2")})
}
```

The console result is what I want:

```
 task1  
 task2
```

But when I try to refactor my code:

```
$onInit() { 
    this.$http.get('/api/example')
        .then(() => {console.log("task1")})
        .then(aFunction())
}  

aFunction() {
    console.log("task2")
}
```

The console result is:

```
 task2  
 task1
```

**Why this happens ?**

Nb: `.then(() => {this.aFunction()});` seems to work but not seems to be a clean solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be passing function reference like `.then(aFunction)` instead of function call. Currently you are doing `aFunction()` is immediately invoking that function.

```
$onInit() { 
    this.$http.get('/api/example')
        .then(() => {console.log("task1")})
        .then(aFunction)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`aFunction` is executed immediately and its result passed into the `.then()`.

It should be : `.then(aFunction)`

This will pass a reference to the `.then` which it will execute itself.